# Return or highlight only new values in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck in one of the tricky problem. I have a textarea having some strings already in it. What I am trying is, when the user put new values in the textarea, they should be displayed highlighted (green), only the new ones, the old ones should remain colorless. And if the user removes the strings from the textarea, the removed values should be highlighted as red. I am using plain JS and HTML. What I have tried is below.

```js
function f() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
  var scopeResult = document.getElementById('scopeResult');
  var scopes = document.getElementById('scopes').value;
  if (checkBox.checked === true) {
    scopeResult.style.display = 'block';
    addOrRemoveScope(scopes);
  } else {
    scopeResult.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function addOrRemoveScope(val) {
  document.getElementById("scopeResult").innerHTML = val.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n])/g, ",<br/>");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="scopes" class="form-control" field="*{scope}" rows="10" maxlength="4096" onchange="addOrRemoveScope(this.value)">
</textarea>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" required onclick="f()" />
<label for="checkbox"> Are you sure, you want to modify the scopes?*</label><br>
<p id="scopeResult" style="display: none; background-color: #5cb85c"></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet? The W3C validator doesn't understand some of the syntax (th:id e.g.).

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for that, it was for thymeleaf. I edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

`replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n])/g, ",<br/>")` is not going to help solve the problem.

Really you should look into a robust lib that does text diff, but to answer.

Based entirely on the position of the value compared to the original value.

> When the user put new values in the textarea, they should be displayed
> highlighted (green), only the new ones.

New values can replace old ones, so I would opt in to making them red, and new new values would be green, essentially any new value longer then the original string length is green everything else is treated as changed, which would be red

> The old ones should remain colourless. And if the user removes the
> strings from the textarea, the removed values should be highlighted as
> red.

Easy enough if is all based on position. As said if you want something more robust look into using a lib. Or use something like the following:

Split the original string and new value into arrays, then loop over original string char by char and if is the same, then dont apply styling, if it's not the same then treat as changed (red), if it does not exist in new array then its deleted, so use the original char as the value.

Then use slice to pick only the new chars in the new value as they will be all new, then join both together.

```js
let original = document.getElementById('input').value;

function process() {

  let letters_original = [...original]
  let letters_current = [...document.getElementById('input').value]

  let b = letters_original.map(
    (v, i) => letters_current[i] === v ? v : `<span style="color:red">${letters_current[i] || v}</span>`
  )
  let c = letters_current.slice(b.length).map(
    v => `<span style="color:green">${v}</span>`
  )

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = [...b, ...c].join('')
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows="10" maxlength="4096" oninput="process()">123</textarea>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Your code is not working properly. Try this, add 4 and 5. Then remove 3, 4 and 5. Then again add 6, 7 and 8

Comment: it works as said throughout answer is **all based on the chars positions in the original value**, why would adding then removing make any diff to the final output?